# Is my code correctly translating the specific conditions that must be met?

Tags: c, if-statement

I have a function that will return a 1 if the specific "badge" or "achievement" is earned, a 0 if the "badge" isn't earned, and a -1 if x and y aren't in the interval [1, 20].

In order for the function to return a 1, or in other words, in order to earn a badge, the field must support four full harvests a year (but does not support five full harvests)

The second condition that must be met is that the cumulative annual cost of planting is between 190 and 250 units.

And the third condition is that the field must bring profit.

NOTE: I already have these predefined functions that I can use to help me in writing this code:
[image]

I already know there are probably problems with my code for the first and second condition, but I just can't figure out how to translate these conditions into my code.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define YEAR 360
#define FULLHARVESTS 4.0

int badgeInQuattro(int x, int y) {
   double harv, annucost, fprofit, harvyear;
   int quattrobadge;

   if ((x >= 1 && x <= 20) && (y >= 1 && y <= 20)) {
      harv = harvestTime(x, y);
      annucost = pricePerUnit(x, y);
      fprofit = fieldProfit(x, y);
      harvyear = (YEAR)/(FULLHARVESTS);

      if (harv == harvyear && annucost > 190 && annucost < 250 && fprofit > 0) {
         quattrobadge = 1;
      }
      else {
         quattrobadge = 0;
      }
   }
   else {
      quattrobadge = -1;
   }

   return quattrobadge;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any fundamental problems in your code. Must be some logic error. Try adding *printf*'s in forking points to see the program flow.

Comment: So is the idea of dividing the year by 4 correct for the first condition that must be satisfied? And if I need the cumulative annual cost, I was thinking, don't I have to multiply the pricePerUnit by 365?

Comment: Karen, what you ask is already a program logic..;) If you want answers to such questions, give us an example of the results you get and the ones you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually find that code can be made *more* readable with multiple exit points, specifically those that can be detected early and especially in the case where your function can be viewed easily, such as the shorter version below.

People often cite multiple exit points as an issue without understanding *why.* It's because it can make the flow of control hard to understand and that's something that doesn't happen for very short functions. Hence I would start with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define YEAR 360
#define FULLHARVESTS 4.0

int badgeInQuattro(int x, int y) {
    double harv, annucost, fprofit, harvyear;

    // Catch invalid ranges first.

    if (x < 1 || x > 20 || y < 1 || y > 20) return -1;

    harv     = harvestTime (x, y);
    annucost = pricePerUnit (x, y);
    fprofit  = fieldProfit (x, y);
    harvyear = (YEAR) / (FULLHARVESTS);

    //printf ("harv     = %f\n", harv);
    //printf ("annucost = %f\n", annucost);
    //printf ("fprofit  = %f\n", fprofit);
    //printf ("harvyear = %f\n", harvyear);

    // Reversing the checks allows for multiple independent return reasons.

    if (harv != harvyear)                   return 0;
    if (annucost <= 190 || annucost >= 250) return 0;
    if (fprofit <= 0)                       return 0;

    // All those failures above have been avoided, we MUST be okay here.

    return 1;
}
```

I would also (temporarily) uncomment out those `printf` statements since, if there are problems with your data, that should show what it is pretty quickly.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. :) But, does my math/calculations for the variables look okay? I was reading over my code and I realized that I need the annual cost, so wouldn't that mean I would have to do something like: annucost = pricePerUnit(x, y) * 365?

Comment: @Karen, only if the price per unit is measured in somethings per day (which seems unlikely - at a pinch it may be the price of a harvest which means you'd need to multiply it by 4 to get a yearly price). It's not _entirely_ clear in all cases what those values are actually measuring but the printing out of the variables should be able to help.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for your help! And I just wanted to say thanks for being so polite and helpful!